# Remove a change from an ealier bazaar commit

Tags: bazaar, rebase

I am working on a feature branch in bazaar. For the purposes of building the project locally, I modified a file locally (`build`), although I do not want this change to be included in my commits. Most of the time I remember to exclude that file from `bzr commit`, or aborted when seeing the summary, but a few commits ago I did overlook it and now the local change has entered the history.

Before submitting my branch, I’d like to clean this up. Is there a way to remove that change from the earlier commit without reverting to the state before and re-doing all commits? Naturally, this does involve rewriting history.

For clarification: In git, I would use `git rebase -i` and just edit the commit.

Comment: You can use `git bzr`

Answer (score 2):

The [bzr-rewrite](https://launchpad.net/bzr-rewrite) plugin provides the same functionality as `git rebase`. It should be bundled with the installers for Windows and Mac OS X. For Linux, depending on your distribution, it may be a separate package.

EDIT: The bzr-rewrite plugin doesn't provide an interactive mode, so it wouldn't be of help in this situation.

Comment: From the documentation is seems that `bzr-rewrite` only provides the functionality of a non-interactive `git rebase`. Can you elaborate how I solve my problem with `bzr-rewrite`?

Comment: Ah, you're right, it doesn't have an interactive mode. Sorry, I thought it did.

Comment: Maybe the comments on this bug report about the lack of interactive mode may help: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bzr-rewrite/+bug/307302